# How to implement startup sanity checks in Nuxt3 server (nitro)?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I have a simple webapp written in Nuxt3 which reads some environment variables as configs to run. For example, it reads `DATA_DIR` to know where it should read/write data to, and this config is critical, meaning - the webapp can't function without a valid `DATA_DIR` value.

I would like to run some code at server startup to perform some sanity checks as the server comes up, and fail the server (stop it before it starts listening on a port) with a helpful error message(s).

This comes up to 2 questions:

1. **How to run code in the server before it starts listening but after it read the configs?**
2. **How to tell the server to shutdown at this point?**

Ideally, I'm looking for something like this:

```js
//this is made up - but ideally something similar exists and runs before the server start listening
defineNitroStartup((nitroApp) => {
  const dataDir = nitroApp.getConfig("dataDir")
  if (typeof dataDir !== 'string') {
    console.error("FATAL: dataDir must be defined")
    nitroApp.exit(1) //also made up, but I hope something similar exists
  }
}
```

Of course, if there's a different way to define config validation, in such a way that the server won't start listening if it fails, that would be even better, but I didn't find any in the docs...